# Select rows from table with specific string value endings from list

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause, sql-like, in-clause

I have a table with two columns **item_name**, **value** where **item_names** looks like "abracadabra_prefix.tag_name". And I need to select rows with tag_names from a list that doesn't have a prefix.

Should be somthing like:

```
tag_names = ['f1', 'k500', '23_g']

SELECT * FROM table WHERE item_name IN (LIKE "%{tag_names});
```

input table:

| item_name | value |
| --- | --- |
| fasdaf.f1 | 1 |
| asdfe.f2 | 2 |
| eywvs.24_g | 2 |
| asdfe.l500 | 2 |
| asdfe.k500 | 2 |
| eywvs.23_g | 2 |

output table:

| item_name | value |
| --- | --- |
| fasdaf.f1 | 1 |
| asdfe.k500 | 2 |
| eywvs.23_g | 2 |

I have tried concatenating a string in a loop to get a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE item_name LIKE '%f1' OR item_name LIKE '%k500' OR item_name LIKE '%23_g';
```

But I can have from 1 to 200 tags, and with a large number of tags, this makes the query too complicated,as I understand it.

Comment: You might have to use regular expression. Still, what is the SQL database you are using?

Comment: Can you update your post with sample input table and expected output table?

Comment: Put your tag values in a (temporary) table and JOIN.

Comment: @lemon yes please!

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu Postgres, MySQL, SQLite. Postgres is most often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the suffix of `item_name` using `substring` with regexp and then use the `any` operator for comparison in the `where` clause.

```sql
select * from the_table
where substring (item_name from '\.(\w+)$') = any('{f1,k500,23_g}'::text[]);
```

SQL fiddle [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aMBoP2VDE9ks3155uccYX2/1)
If you intend to use the query as a parameterized one then it will be convenient to replace `'{f1,k500,23_g}'::text[]` with `string_to_array('f1,k500,23_g', ',')`, i.e. pass the list of suffixes as a comma-separated string. Please note that this query will result in a sequential scan.

Comment: Thank you, it doesn't work with string_to_array(), but work with any(Array['f1,k500,23_g']). And  work fast)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

- `UNNEST` to extract tag values from your array,
- `CROSS JOIN` to associate tag value to each row of your table
- `LIKE` to make a comparison between your item_name and your tag

```
SELECT item_name, value_ 
FROM tab
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY['f1', 'k500', '23_g']) AS tag
WHERE item_name LIKE '%' || tag || '%'
```

Output:

| item_name | value_ |
| --- | --- |
| fasdaf.f1 | 1 |
| asdfe.k500 | 2 |
| eywvs.23_g | 2 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gj2USTL5wQcFTyYxdanTtB/0).